# Adding Auto Increment column in destination SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis, oledb, auto-increment

I am creating a package in SSIS and this will insert records based on the look up operation as like below .

**Source** : View 
**Destination** : Table

[image]

NOw I have an issue while inserting record i need to insert into a destination column which is not in the source and that column needs to be autoincremented by 1. How to do it here.

Any suggestion is welcome ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us say the column name is "Id". If column "Id" already has an identity to it, then you're good. If not, then in your destination table you will have to create a new identity column, remove the "Id" column and then rename new column to "Id".

ALTER TABLE (yourTable) ADD NewColumn INT IDENTITY(1,1)
ALTER TABLE (yourTable) DROP COLUMN Id
EXEC sp_rename 'yourTable.NewColumn', 'Id', 'COLUMN'

After this in your SSIS destination do not map any column from the source to Id column and the Id column in database will start from value 1 and automatically increment by a value of 1. Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to add increment from the ssis itself,

Comment: You need to have a variable for Row Number and increment that using a Script Task. This should help: https://www.hansmichiels.com/2015/11/13/how-to-add-a-rownumber-to-a-data-flow-task-in-ssis-2012/

Answer (score 1):

You could add to target table column defined as `IDENTITY/AUTO_INCREMENT/DEFAULT sequence_name.NEXTVAL`.

In your SSIS package you need to skip that column to allow DB to populate that column.

Comment: there lies the catch, we cant change it to identity column coz its the standard we have to implement here

Comment: i am looking for making it work from the ssis itself